# AngularJS how to properly use ng-model as a class?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I read the angularjs docs and it says you can use `ng-model` directive as a class like this:

`<input class="ng-model">`

My issue is, I want to bind this input to a variable like `test`. How do I do this?
I tried using

`<input class="ng-model='test'">`
`<h1>{{test}}</h1>`

but it's not working..

How do I do this? Please help.

Comment: @shaunhusain Can't use any directive that's why I want the class to work :(

Comment: why use angular if you can't use directives? why can't you use directives?  Even going back to IE6 (if you must) you can still use directives you just have to define things a bit differently.

Comment: I'm trying to use angularjs with Gravity Forms. In gravity forms, you can only set the class, so I'm trying to make the ng-model work using class as stated in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

ngModel docs are wrong and require updating.

ngModel directive definition object [does not have](https://github.com/adnan-i/angular.js/blob/v1.0.7/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1080) a `restrict` property, which means that it will work only with the attributes, as in:

```html
<input ng-model="test" />
```

So you're out of luck. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ng-class directive. In the example below, the css-class will be applied when isCssClass (i.e. $scope.isCssClass) is true.

`<input ng-class="{css-class: isCssClass}">`

Comment: sorry I can't use ng-class either.. I'm only limited to changing the class of an input...

Comment: @Melvin that is what ng-class does.